# error trying to access kafka metrics through jmx programmatically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx

I just started with a simple example to read the jmx metrics and used the simple values of HeapMemoryUsage, CPUTime etc to get the feel for it. I need to try and access the kafka server / consumer metrics specifically lag which I can see is visible as a key in the jconsole app under FetcherLagMetrics-ConsumerLag. But programmaticaly I get the following error:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: kafka.consumer:type=consumer- 
  fetch-manager-metrics
```

This tells me that the consumer-fetch-manager metrics is the issue as it is not present even in the jconsole. I changed it to the following & still the same issue:

```
consumerBean = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new 
   ObjectName("kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics"),"ConsumerLag");
            cd = (CompositeData) consumerBean;
```

The code trying to access these values is as follows:

```
        jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().invoke(new 
         ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory"), "gc", null, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            //get an instance of the HeapMemoryUsage Mbean
            memoryMbean = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Memory"), "HeapMemoryUsage");
            cd = (CompositeData) memoryMbean;

            //get an instance of the OperatingSystem Mbean
            osMbean = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"),"ProcessCpuTime");

            //get an instance of the kafka metrics Mbean
            consumerBean = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new ObjectName("kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics"),"MaxLag");
            cd = (CompositeData) consumerBean;

            consumerBeanII = jmxCon.getMBeanServerConnection().getAttribute(new ObjectName("kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,name=ConsumerLag"),"Lag");


            System.out.println("Used memory: " + " " + cd.get("MaxLag") + " Used cpu: " + consumerBean); //print memory usage

            tempMemory = tempMemory + Long.parseLong(cd.get("used").toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000); //delay for one second

        }
```

It fails at line consumerBean = ......Could someone please explain or provide the correct way to access the kafka metrics using jmx /JMI implementation?

Comment: Did you try to provide a Client id? `kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)`

Comment: I don't understand the hierarchy in MBeans so not sure which one is the client id as there are multiple subfolders - kafka.server --->  FetcherLagMetrics  -->  ConsumerLag --->  
      ReplicaFetcherThread-0-2 ---> data.in  ---> 5 ---> Attributes ---> 
      Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your version of Kafka, but when I look at mine (v1.1.0) using JConsole there is no such bean for consumer lag that you describe. Therefore I think it is expected that your JMX query will fail.

Instead, I believe this kind of information was moved to the [Kafka Admin API](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroups--) interface. So you must use this now to get lag settings, if you don't want to use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` command-line utility.

For us we only need these stats for monitoring, so we are using https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter to obtain the info for Prometheus.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I focused too much on getting the consumer metrics from the broker but given the version 1.0.0 we are using, this was a mistake. The consumer metrics are exposed only on the consumer process servers. So just to confirm; you are saying that this in only retrievable using the kafka admin api, which would be on the brokers servers right?

Comment: Yes, you can use Kafka Admin API to connect to broker servers and query for consumergroup details. This is same api that `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool uses internally so if you want to write your own code then use this one.